# Why doesn't my bitmask program work? And how can i reset / set a bit and then print the number

Tags: c, mask, bitmask

```
int main() {

    unsigned int nr, mask;

    printf("nr = ");   //for eg. if i use number 11111111 or 00111111 it prints 0. 
    scanf("%hu", &nr);

    if ((nr & 0b00001000) == 0)
        printf("0\n\n");
    else
        printf("1\n\n");

mask = 0b00001000;

    if (nr & mask)
        printf("1\n");
    else
        printf("0\n");

    printf("%x", nr);

    return 0;
}
```

I can set a reset a bit using a mask like this `00001000 & nr(10101010)` with the "1" placed so the 4th bit will be rest, but again it doesn't work ( I don't know why). But I have no idea how to print the number after.

Comment: C and C++ are different language. Would you mind choosing one?

Comment: I would like in c. I looked at that, but I wanted to try this way, if it can be done. I am very new to programing  so yeah

Comment: *"with the "1" placed so the 4th bit will be rest"* - `1 & 1` is still `1`. You might want to re-think that.

Comment: `scanf("%hu", &nr);` invokes *undefined behavior* due to type mismatch: `%hu` expectes `unsigned short*`, but passed thing is `unsigned int*`.

Comment: if I change it to unsigned short nr, mask It still doesnt work with numbers like 11111111 or 00111111

Answer (score 1):

`scanf()` don't have options to read binary string, so you will have to read as string and do conversion by yourself.

For example (error checking is omitted):

```
char nr_str[128];
scanf("%127s", nr_str);
nr = 0;
for (int i = 0; nr_str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    nr = (nr << 1) | (nr_str[i] - '0');
}
```

Comment: If i try using the number 10001000 and mask 00001000 it works.

Comment: @Bufni `10001000` in decimal is `100110001001101001101000` in binary and the 4th bit counted from LSB is `1`. You are (un)lucky!